# Is there any way to call a function when a record is requested to be shown in a form view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I would like to update every record when it is shown in form view. Is there anyway to define some sort of a callback to update the record BEFORE it is shown?

One method that I could think of is by adding a dummy field to form view with an `on_change` attribute. But it feels kinda hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *function field*. Function is called when the form loading and at the time of new record creation before and after.

When you create a new record this function field will take value as a *William* and after saving value will change and become *odedra*

Here is example of *char* return type of function :

```
def _default_get(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    print " This function called before new record create " 
    res = 'William'
    return res      

def _set_value(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    print " This function called at time of saving record and form view load "
    res = {}
    for i in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[i.id] = 'odedra'
    return res

_columns = {
    'value': fields.function(_set_value, type='char', string='Value'),
}

_defaults = {
    'value': _default_get, 
}
```

*NOTE:*

As per your requirement, you may change function field return type.

Comment: That's a great alternative! I'll choose this as the best answer if there isn't any better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a functional field seems odd but then making a read not idempotent is also unusual.

I would set a context in the window action of your form so you can test for it and limit the effect of this and then override the default_get method for new records and the read method for existing records on your model.